# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple' ,ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, valueerror

> I'm calling this function to get predicted price for a car

```
def predict_price(car_model,condition,body,transmission,fuel,year,capacity,mileage):
    car_model_index = np.where(X.columns==car_model)[0][0]
    condtion_index = np.where(X.columns==condition)[0][0]
    body_index = np.where(X.columns==body)[0][0]
    trans_index = np.where(X.columns==transmission)[0][0]
    fuel_index = np.where(X.columns==fuel)[0][0]
    
    x = np.zeros(len(X.columns))
    x[0] = year,
    x[1] = capacity,
    x[2] = mileage,
    if car_model_index>0:
        x[car_model_index] = 1
    if condtion_index>0:
        x[condtion_index] = 1
    if body_index>0:
        x[body_index] = 1
    if trans_index>0:
        x[trans_index] = 1
    if fuel_index>0:
        x[fuel_index] = 1
    
    return lr.predict([x])[0]

predict_price('Toyota CHR','Used','SUV','Automatic','Petrol',2018,1200,26400)
```

> Expecting to get the predicted price but getting an error like this, TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple' ,ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-536-2e08ba5e0e1e> in <module>
----> 1 predict_price('Toyota CHR','Used','SUV','Automatic','Petrol',2018,1200,26400)

<ipython-input-525-e4e4a4d425fb> in predict_price(car_model, condition, body, transmission, fuel, year, capacity, mileage)
      7 
      8     x = np.zeros(len(X.columns))
----> 9     x[0] = year,
     10     x[1] = capacity,
     11     x[2] = mileage,

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: is `year` a tuple?

Comment: you just have to remove the `comma sign` after the `year, capacity and mileage`. The year is taken as `(2018,)...essentially a tuple` , since you put a comma there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @Priya suggested, you need to remove the `,` after `year`, `capacity` and `mileage`:

```py
def predict_price(car_model,condition,body,transmission,fuel,year,capacity,mileage):
    car_model_index = np.where(X.columns==car_model)[0][0]
    condtion_index = np.where(X.columns==condition)[0][0]
    body_index = np.where(X.columns==body)[0][0]
    trans_index = np.where(X.columns==transmission)[0][0]
    fuel_index = np.where(X.columns==fuel)[0][0]
    
    x = np.zeros(len(X.columns))
    x[0] = year  # here
    x[1] = capacity  # here
    x[2] = mileage  # and here
    if car_model_index>0:
        x[car_model_index] = 1
    if condtion_index>0:
        x[condtion_index] = 1
    if body_index>0:
        x[body_index] = 1
    if trans_index>0:
        x[trans_index] = 1
    if fuel_index>0:
        x[fuel_index] = 1
    
    return lr.predict([x])[0]

predict_price('Toyota CHR','Used','SUV','Automatic','Petrol',2018,1200,26400)
```

Indeed, the comma `,` is the symbol used to create a tuple:

```py
>>> year = 2018
>>> foo = year
>>> foo
2018
>>> type(foo)
<class 'int'>
>>> bar = year,
>>> bar
(2018,)
>>> type(bar)
<class 'tuple'>
```